# How to add Bullseye code coverage to code compiled with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, bullseye

How to add Bullseye code coverage to code compiled with gcc?

See my answer below.

Comment: It’s generally considered preferable if the question only includes the question, and you write an answer for your own question, instead of putting both the question and answer in the question.

Comment: fixed as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to Stackoverflow since I could not find the answer anywhere and had to contact Bullseye support.

The answer is in this page (from Bullseye support):

http://www.bullseye.com/help/build-integration.html

The short version:
(for Windows; assuming Bullseye is already installed):

Open a command shell

1. Turn code coverage ON:

   `cov01 -1`
2. Write your compile command exactly as you would normally, but pass it as an argument to Bullseye `covc.exe` program (in the bin folder of the Bullseye installed folder).

Example:

`covc -i gcc main.c  -o myProgram.exe`

Comment: what about using it with x86_64-vmk-linux-gnu-gcc ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't work with linux. Try contacting Bullseye tech support - this is how I got my answer for Windows.

Comment: thanks, fixed by:
                $ cd .../BullseyeCoverage/bin
                $ ln -s covc x86_64-vmk-linux-gnu-gcc